# Powershell dot-sourcing variables inside variables not expanding

Tags: powershell

I've got the following problem:

Say I have 2 powershell scripts, named A.ps1 and conf.ps1.

conf.ps1 contents are just a few vars that will be dot-sourced by A.ps1, like this:

```
$dateLogs          = Get-Date -UFormat '%Y%m%d'
$installDir        = 'C:\Gcloud\'
$logDir            = '$installDir\GcloudLogs'
$logFile           = '$logDir\$dateLogs\logFile.txt'
```

When imported, funny thing is that `$dateLogs` is expanded and in the debugger I can see `"..\20190805\logFile.txt"` but `$installDir`, for some reason, won't expand.

So instead of having `$logFile = "C:\Gcloud\GcloudLogs\20190805\logFile.txt"` I end up having `"$installDir\GcloudLogs\20190805\logFile.txt"`and that `$installDir` won't ever expand to its real value.

Am I missing something?

Any lead would be much appreciatd since I've been struggling for a long time with this. I tried several things like:

```
- ${$installDir}\GcloudLogs
- $($installDir\GcloudLogs)
- $(${installDir}\GcloudLogs)
```

With single quotes, double quotes and no quotes at all... None of that worked out.

Thank you all beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to not confuse single or double quotes and to save you from getting paths with double backslashes, it is always safer to use the [Join-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-6) cmdlet.

```
$dateLogs   = '{0:yyyyMMdd}' -f (Get-Date)                                # a more 'PowerShelly' way of formatting a date
$installDir = 'C:\Gcloud'
$logDir     = Join-Path -Path $installDir -ChildPath 'GcloudLogs'
$logFile    = Join-Path -Path $logDir -ChildPath "$dateLogs\logFile.txt"  # use double-quotes here
```

It is also possible to use the .NET `[System.IO.Path]::Combine()` function

```
$dateLogs   = '{0:yyyyMMdd}' -f (Get-Date)
$installDir = 'C:\Gcloud'
$logDir     = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($installDir, "GcloudLogs")
$logFile    = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($logDir, $dateLogs, "logFile.txt")
```

Both methods will create these paths:

> ```
> $logDir   --> C:\Gcloud\GcloudLogs
> $logFile  --> C:\Gcloud\GcloudLogs\20190805\logFile.txt
> ```

Comment: Although my experience is consistent with emilast's answer to this question, this is the better solution simply because it's more reliable. I believe that the two code blocks are actually equivalent; I seem to recall reading somewhere that `Join-Path` is a wrapper for `[System.IO.Path]::Combine()`.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin AFAIK the `Join-Path` only has the `-AdditionalChildPath` parameter as of PowerShell 6. To me (using PS 5.1) this makes using the `[System.IO.Path]::Combine()` with three path elements just a tad more elegant.

Comment: Perhaps, though I wouldn't hesitate to `Join-Path -Path $root -ChildPath (Join-Path -Path $subdir -ChildPath $leaf)`.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's awesome. I didn't know cmdlet Join-Path nor Combine(), you've been very enlightening, thank you @Theo.

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between single and double quotes in string constants in Powershell. Try using double quotes instead.